# Explicit Type Conversion and typeof in JavaScript

Tags: javascript

```
    var x = +"5";    // 5
    alert("string to number explicitly: "+typeof x); //  number
```

Now consider this:

When we ***convert*** a ***string*** to a ***number***, the result is the ***numeric*** value of a ***string*** if it is simply a ***number***; ***all other strings become NaN***

```
var y = +"foo";  //NaN
alert(typeof y); // Why this results in number?
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`typeof NaN` is as a `"number"`     and it's expected behavior. 
Further information: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/NaN

Comment: The definitive reference is [*ECMA-262 §11.4.3*](http://ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-11.4.3) (also see [*§4.3.20*](http://ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-4.3.20)). ;-)

Answer (score 0):

Its shortest form to convert a variable to number. `+anything` is trying to convert `anything` to number.

As `"foo"` is a string and not a valid number thus it returns `NaN`